# save string to core data via helper class func

Tags: swift, string, core-data, parameters

In my swift code below I am trying to save a string into core data using a helper class.
Right now my code is causing a runtime error stating Cannot assign value of type 'Data' to type 'String?' at imageInstance.text = data. I did something similar trying to save a image and it worked. I also added a core data photo

[core data pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OioFo.png)

```
class DataBaseHelper {
    
    static let shareInstance = DataBaseHelper()
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    func saveText(data: Data) {
        let imageInstance = Info(context: context)
        imageInstance.txt = data
        
     
            
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("text is saved")
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    
   
}
```

BASE CLASS

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 DataBaseHelper.shareInstance.saveText(data: "Jessica")}
```

Comment: According to your model `txt` is clearly a string attribute. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @vadian I added the base class check out how I am trying to save the string in view did load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be more careful how you name your functions.

You are going to ***save Text(*** so the parameter label `data` is misleading and the type `Data` is wrong.

Replace

```
func saveText(data: Data) {
```

with

```
func saveText(data: String) {
```

or – more meaningful because `text` is already a part of the function name

```
func saveText(_ string: String) {
    let imageInstance = Info(context: context)
    imageInstance.txt = string
```

and call it

```
DataBaseHelper.shareInstance.saveText("Jessica")
```